# How to auto increment and decrement count when I tap Button

Tags: ios, swift, nsnumberformatter

I have two buttons called "+" and "-".

If I tap "+" button I have to increment count value up to max "7" and if I tap "-" button I have to reduce the count value if the value reached to "1" the value must not change because minimum I have "1" as Default.

Here's my sample code:

```
@IBAction func seat_btns(sender: AnyObject) {

    if sender.tag == 10 {

        let i : Int!

        let s = self.seatNumberLabel.text
        if let x = Int(s!) {
            i = x + 1
            self.seatNumberLabel.text = i.description

        }

    }
    else if sender.tag == 20 {
        let s = self.seatNumberLabel.text
        let i : Int!

        if let x = Int(s!) {
            i = x - 1
            self.seatNumberLabel.text = i.description

    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple `if` checks can help you here

```
@IBAction func seat_btns(sender: AnyObject) {

    if sender.tag == 10 {

        let i : Int!

        let s = self.seatNumberLabel.text
        if let x = Int(s!) {
            if (x < 7) {
                i = x + 1
                self.seatNumberLabel.text = i.description
            }
        }

    }
    else if sender.tag == 20 {
        let s = self.seatNumberLabel.text
        let i : Int!

        if let x = Int(s!) {
            if (x > 1) {
                i = x - 1
                self.seatNumberLabel.text = i.description
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for max 7

```
i = max(1, min(x + 1, 7))
```

for min 1

```
 i = max(1, min(x - 1, 7))
```

Edited:

```
if sender.tag == 10 {

        let i : Int!

        let s = self.seatNumberLabel.text
        if let x = Int(s!) {
                i = max(1, min(x + 1, 7)
                self.seatNumberLabel.text = i.description
        }

    }
    else if sender.tag == 20 {
        let s = self.seatNumberLabel.text
        let i : Int!

        if let x = Int(s!) {
                i = max(1, min(x - 1, 7)
                self.seatNumberLabel.text = i.description
        }
}
```

Comment: I think you're missing some closing parentheses

Comment: On the first two statements you make, `i = max(1, min(x + 1, 7)` and `i = max(1, min(x - 1, 7)`, you only have one closing parenthesis.